# AWS CLI script to change security group of EC2 to match currently assigned IP address when using VPN to obfuscate network traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, vpn

If I'm using a VPN service that dynamically changes my IP address, is there a way to write a script that I can run with the AWS CLI to update the IP address (the one provided by the VPN at that particular moment in time) on my AWS VPC Security Group that allows SSH access to the EC2 instance via TCP/Port 22?

Also, how would I disable it automatically when the VPN provider changes my IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shell script I use to add my current IP address to a security group:

```
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "VPN-SSH-SG" --protocol tcp --port 22   --cidr $IP/32 --output text
```

You'll need to update it for the name of your Security Group.

Here's a Python script to automatically delete all rules from a Security Group:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3

GROUP_NAME = "VPN-SSH-SG"

# Connect to the Amazon EC2 service
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

# Retrieve the security group
security_groups = ec2.security_groups.filter(Filters=[{'Name':'group-name', 'Values':[GROUP_NAME]}])

# Delete all rules in the group
for group in security_groups:
    group.revoke_ingress(IpPermissions = group.ip_permissions)
```

You could combine them together to clear existing entries and then add your current IP address.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have many environments and many security groups, here is python script to update it all once your home ip is changed:

```py
import boto3
import urllib3
import sys
from datetime import datetime

CURRENT_IP = "4x.1xx.2xx.2xx/32"  # Fixed old ip

GROUP_MAP = {
    "profile1": [
        {
            "GroupId": ["sg-xxx"],
            "Description": "Description",
            "FromPort": 443
            # "ToPort": optional to port
        }
    ],
    "profile2": [
        {
            "GroupId": ["sg-xxx"],
            "Description": "proxy",
            "FromPort": 22
        }
    ]
}


def get_new_ip():
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/')
    ip = r.data.decode("utf-8").strip('\n')
    return ip + '/32'


def update_for_profile(data, old_ip, new_ip, profile_name):
    print(f"{profile_name}: Updating for {data.get('Description', '')} {data['GroupId']}")
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    groups = ec2.security_groups.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'group-id', 'Values': data['GroupId']}])
    from_port = data["FromPort"]
    to_port = data.get('ToPort', from_port)
    ip_protocol = data.get('ip_protocol', 'tcp')
    cidr_ip = old_ip
    description = f"Added {datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
    try:
        for group in groups:
            group.revoke_ingress(
                FromPort=from_port,
                IpProtocol=ip_protocol,
                CidrIp=cidr_ip,
                ToPort=to_port
            )
            group.authorize_ingress(
                IpPermissions=[dict(
                    FromPort=from_port,
                    IpProtocol=ip_protocol,
                    ToPort=to_port,
                    IpRanges=[{
                        'CidrIp': new_ip,
                        'Description': description
                    }])
                ]
            )
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)


def update_my_ip(old_ip, new_ip):
    for profile_name, mapping in GROUP_MAP.items():
        boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=profile_name)
        for item in mapping:
            update_for_profile(item, old_ip, new_ip, profile_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_ip = get_new_ip()
    old_ip = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else CURRENT_IP
    if not old_ip:
        print("There's no old ip")
    print(f"Updating my ip from {old_ip} to {new_ip}")
    update_my_ip(old_ip, new_ip)
```

Thank you for your answers above

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;DR** You can configure rule's source to be a CIDR block, which matches your VPN address space.

A security group acts as a virtual firewall for your instance to control inbound and outbound traffic. For each security group, you add rules that control the inbound traffic to instances, and a separate set of rules that control the outbound traffic.

Here we are interested in the inbound rules. Each rule contains the source of the traffic and the destination port or port range. The source can be another security group, an **IPv4 or IPv6 CIDR** block, a single IPv4 or IPv6 address, or a prefix list ID.

When you specify a CIDR block as the source for a rule, traffic is allowed from the specified addresses for the specified protocol and port. If you specify a single IPv4 address, specify the address using the /32 prefix length. For example `127.0.0.1/32` will only allow access from this particular IP. However, if we define our CIDR block like  `127.0.0.1/8` all IP addresses starting with 127. will be allowed. For example, `127.123.123.123` would be allowed.

Therefore, you can configure rule's source to be a CIDR block, which matches your VPN address space.

Best, Stefan

Comment: Having a CIDR block wouldn't really help here since I want to lock it down according to my current VPN's provided IP address. I was looking for some way to update the security group via the AWS CLI. I've updated the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Per John Rotenstein's answer above, I modified it and wrote it into a Lambda function. Works great now! Hope this helps anyone else.

```
import boto3
import urllib3

# %% Description
'''Update the IP address to connect with a VPN that
dynamically changes user IPs.'''
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # %% Get current IP in CIDR notation
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/')
    ip = r.data.decode("utf-8").strip('\n')
    CidrIp_new = ip + '/32'
    
    # %% Revoke old permissions
    sg = boto3.resource('ec2').SecurityGroup('sg-ce95e5d5')
    permissions = sg.ip_permissions
    FromPort = permissions[0].get('FromPort')
    IpProtocol = permissions[0].get('IpProtocol')
    CidrIp = permissions[0].get('IpRanges')[0].get('CidrIp')
    ToPort = permissions[0].get('ToPort')
    revoke_resp = sg.revoke_ingress(
        FromPort=FromPort, IpProtocol=IpProtocol,
        CidrIp=CidrIp, ToPort=ToPort
        )
    
    # %% Authorize new sg parameters
    auth_resp = sg.authorize_ingress(
        FromPort=FromPort, IpProtocol=IpProtocol,
        CidrIp=CidrIp_new, ToPort=ToPort
        )
    
    return 'Revoke Status', revoke_resp, 'Authorize Status', auth_resp
```