# Allowing Users to Modify their rules with their public ip in existing EC2 security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, jenkins, devops, aws-security-group

Currently, when a person's public IP address changes because of ISP issues, I have to manually go into EC2 console and change the inbound rule associated with that person to allow them access. There are multiple inbound rules within a security group and multiple security groups that this person is whitelisted for Rather than changing, for instance, 5 rules manually, Is there's a way to launch a script through Jenkins job that prompts for the security group name, person's name, and new IP address so that this substitution occurs automatically?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Might be useful: [AWS CLI script to change security group of EC2 to match currently assigned IP address when using VPN to obfuscate network traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68232612/174777)

Comment: Sorry this is not helpful, We are not using VPN here to avoid this only i am trying different approach. Here whenever the user public ip changes we should have jenkins job for the security group name, person's name, and new IP address. When user inputs the data and run job the SG should get updated. Any Advice?

Comment: The above link goes to an Answer of mine that shows how to use the AWS CLI to add IP addresses to a Security Group, and a Python program to remove entries from a Security Group. You could add code like that in a Jenkins job. As written, it obtains the Public IP address and adds it to a rule. Moving it to a Jenkins job would require some means of discovering the IP address that needs to be added.

Comment: Got it, Can we pass parameter in jenkins job asking users to input their public IP,and security group name and with matching rule description the security group should be updated with users IP, i am not popular with scripting so help here would be much appreciated...!

Comment: If the users have access to the Jenkins console, then this is feasible. Or, create some web portal where they can enter the information (eg via a VPN or behind some form of authentication) and trigger an AWS Lambda function to do the update. If they have their own AWS credentials, they can just run the command themselves. Lots of potential ways to cause the update.

Comment: I found this article - https://griggheo.medium.com/modifying-ec2-security-groups-via-aws-lambda-functions-115a1828cdb6#:~:text=This%20is%20useful%20when%20you,to%20ports%2080%20and%20443, I am trying this but couldn't update by passing Jenkins parameter to script.... I am not sure if i doing it right here, can you help me to add pass jenkins parameter to python script ? @John Rotenstein

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234794/discussion-between-naveen-nk-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this using AWS cli with shell script, i can modify the security group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please improvise your comments by giving example